# ¿Porque el case 1 funciona, pero el case 2 no?

Tags: c++

He intentado encontrar una solucion al problema con switch - case y no entiendo que puede estar saliendo mal. El case 1 funciona pero el case 2 no, pero individualmente funcionan.
No alcanzo a ver el problema. Es decir, cuando escojo la opcion 2 del menu, simplemente sale el primer cout y alli termina la ejecucion del programa cuando no deberia ser asi. Esto lo publico asi porque estoy haciendo un programa sencillo con varios switch anidados con el objetivo de guardar la mayor cantidad de ejercicios que pueda mientras aprendo C++.

Espero puedan ayudarme!

'''

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std; 
int main(){
    
    
    cout<<"1. Toma de temperaturas."<<endl;
    cout<<"2. Valores sumados."<<endl;
    int opcion;
    cout<<"Digite una opcion: "; cin>>opcion;
    switch(opcion){
        case 1:{
            /*4.  Escriba  un programa que tome cada 4 horas la temperatura exterior, leyendola durante un periodo de 24 horas. Es decir, debe leer 6 temperaturas. 
        Calcule la temperatura media del dia, la temperatura mas alta y la mas baja*/ 
        cout<<"Toma temperaturas."<<endl; 

        float temperatura, mayor, menor=999, sumat, promedio;
        int i = 0;
        while(i < 24){
            cout<<"Ingrese la temperatura para la hora "<<i<<": "; 
            cin>>temperatura; 
            
            sumat += temperatura; 
            if(temperatura > mayor){
                mayor = temperatura; 
            }
            if(temperatura < menor){
                menor = temperatura; 
            }
            i+=4;
        }
        //for(int i; i < 24; i +=4){
            
            
            
        //} 
        promedio = sumat/6; 
        
        cout<<"\nEl promedio de la temperatura es: "<<promedio<<endl; 
        cout<<"La temperatura mas alta es:  "<<mayor<<endl; 
        cout<<"La temperatura  menor es:  "<<menor<<endl;
        //getch();
            
            
            
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
            /* Escriba un programa que lea valores enteros hasta que se intrduzca el valor en el rango 20 -30 o
            se introduzca un cero. El programa debe entregar la suma de os valores mayores a 0 introducidos*/ 
            cout<<"Valores enteros sumados.";
            int num, suma, s;

            while(s == true){
                cout<<"Introduzca un numero: "; 
                cin>>num;
                if((num == 0 || num >= 20) && num<=30 && num > 0){
                    s = false;
                     
                    //cout<<" Ingreso un : "<<num<<endl; 
                    cout<<"La suma de todos los numeros es: "<<suma; 
                }
                suma += num;
            }
            break;
        }
        default:
            cout<<"Opcion no valida.";
            break;
            
    }
    
    return 0; 
}
```

'''

Comment: Nota: los case no necesitan llaves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el bucle de la opción 2 se debe repetir mientras s sea true, pero no has inicializado s, por eso no entra.
Tampoco inicias la variable suma, te daría un valor erróneo.
En la primera opión debieras inicializar también sumat (sumat = 0)
La solución es tan simple como darle un valor inicial a s para que entre en el bucle.

```
case 2:{
            /* Escriba un programa que lea valores enteros hasta que se intrduzca el valor en el rango 20 -30 o
            se introduzca un cero. El programa debe entregar la suma de os valores mayores a 0 introducidos*/ 
            cout<<"Valores enteros sumados.";
            int num, suma=0, s=true;
```

De esta manera entra en el bucle. También puedes usar un bucle do que se ejecuta al menos una vez, pero también tendrías que darle valor a s.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido mucho.